# Does jClouds supports MS Azure Table storage services

Tags: java, azure-table-storage, jclouds

I know jclouds provides API to interact with MS Azure Blob storage.

But, does jclouds supports / provides API to access MS azure Table storage?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/

Please help with references / samples

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Storage team has a Java client library which provides a simple yet powerful programming model allowing you to work with Azure Storage's blobs, tables and queues. More information can be found at [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library and Tooling Updates @ TechEd 2014](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/16/microsoft-azure-storage-client-library-and-tooling-updates-teched-2014.aspx). We have tried hard to follow established Java conventions so we hope Java developers will really enjoy using this library. Please let us know what you think!

Jason

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look. The reason I am looking at jClouds is, it comes with OSGi compliant bundle.